# Getting biggest document from a collection in the last 24 hours in Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of trades in my Firestore database. The trades have the following relevant data that I need in the query:

```
time: 1589535935410 (milliseconds)
tradeValue: 12343.017
isBuyerMaker: true || false
```

I need to run a query that gets the biggest TradeValue (one in isBuyerMaker true and also in false) in the last 24 hours.
How can I achieve this through Firestore queries?

I tried running this query:

```
const biggestBuyQuery = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("cex-trades")
    .orderBy("time", "desc")
    .where("isBuyerMaker", "==", true)
    .where("time", ">", seconds24h())
    .orderBy("tradeValue", "desc")
    .limit(1);
```

This does get the documents from the last 24 hours but since it is being ordered by time, I do not get the biggest tradeValue

Comment: Couldn't you just order by tradeValue desc and get the first doc?

Comment: That does not orderBy time so I get old documents as well. I have to order by time to get the latest docs

Comment: Also, how to check for isBuyerMaker?

Comment: As stated in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) - Firestore queries can only have an inequality on a single field. As a workaround, you can do `orderBy()` on one field and then filter values on another manually.

Answer (score 0):

From the tags I'm going to assume you're working with the JS firestore API.

**Edit**: I've added workaround that should work for this:

```js
let query = collection
    .where("isBuyerMaker", "==", /* true / false */)
    .where("time", ">", /* now.milliseconds - (24*60*60*1000) */)
    .where("tradeValue", ">=", 0) // New workaround
    .orderBy("tradeValue", "desc")
    .limit(1)
    .get()
```

---

I'd run a compound query with a few where clauses:

```js
let query = collection
    .where("isBuyerMaker", "==", /* true / false */)
    .where("time", ">", /* now.milliseconds - (24*60*60*1000) */)
    .orderBy("tradeValue", "desc")
    .limit(1)
    .get()
```

and collect the 0th document from the promise when it resolved

Comment: `Uncaught FirebaseError: Invalid query. You have a where filter with an inequality (<, <=, !=, not-in, >, or >=) on field 'time' and so you must also use 'time' as your first argument to Query.orderBy(), but your first orderBy() is on field 'tradeValue' instead.`

Comment: This is the error I get when the query runs

Comment: `const biggestBuyQuery = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("cex-trades")
    .orderBy("time", "desc")
    .where("isBuyerMaker", "==", true)
    .where("time", ">", seconds24h())
    .orderBy("tradeValue", "desc")
    .limit(1);`

Comment: I ran this query but it orders by time and hence I do not get the biggest readeValue when I limit to 1

Comment: @Xander: Since `tradeValue` is the primary concern of OP, I'd order/filter on that field first.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how exactly do I make it so I get the latest and biggest tradeValue?

Comment: @Xander `Uncaught FirebaseError: Invalid query. All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, !=, not-in, >, or >=) must be on the same field. But you have inequality filters on 'time' and 'tradeValue'`

Comment: The error on your updated query